# What is the correct steps to start my own project based on a github project template?

Tags: git, github

I would like to start a new web project, and I found CodeIgniter-Bootstrap is a good foundation for me. But what should be my next step? I don't want to fork it because it makes CodeIgniter-Bootstrap appears in my repository list but I want my new project called MyProject. Should I just clone CodeIgniter-Bootstrap into local and rename the folder then import as new repository into github? If so, whenever CodeIgniter-Bootstrap got new ammendments why could I easily sync it from the original project because the linkage is already broken?

I know there is a similar question out there but no solution is provide yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314336/how-to-start-a-project-over-an-existing-project-used-as-a-template

Guys any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would fork it on GitHub (you can rename it in the project settings), just so that it's easy to tell that it is a fork and help give the original authors credit.

Either way, to pull in upstream changes, you add both your fork and the original as remotes to your local repository, fetch from each, merge as you see fit, and push back to your fork.

Comment: not quite sure what do you mean by rename it in project settings, where is this setting? Also how about the project folder, could I rename it as well?

Comment: You can name the repository whatever you want at https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/settings. You can name the directory containing a git repository whatever you want.

Comment: Cool, finally I figure out how to do it. Btw I could still add a remote url to fetch from the forked project afterwards right?

Comment: Certainly. You can add as many remotes to a Git repository as you want.